# Why is the variance of the Wright-Fisher model not equal p(1-p)/(2N)?

Tags: population-genetics

I was looking at the properties of the Binomial probability distribution and [it says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) that the variance is `np(1-p)`. In population genetics, n = 2N. So I would expect to see that the variance is `2Np(1-p)`.

But when looking at the Wright-Fisher model, I often see that the variance is $p(1-p)/(2N)$ ([see this presentation page 6](http://people.bu.edu/msoren/BI515_2014/Lecture4.pdf)).

How to derive the variance of the Wright-Fisher model to get this variance from $Prob\{X=i\}=\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial variance $2N p (1-p)$ is for the number of individuals $n'$ carrying the allele in the next generation. The frequency of the allele in the next generation is $p'=n'/(2N)$, so its variance is $$\text{Var}[p'] = \text{Var}[n'/(2N)] = \text{Var}[n']/(2N)^2 = p(1-p)/(2N).$$

Comment: This is because $Var[n'] = 2Npq$ which is the variance of the binomial model $(2Np(1-p))$ Right? Because $n'$ is also coming from a binomial sampling

Comment: @M.Beausoleil: yes, exactly.